# How can I load templates from subdirectories in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I wanna replace a form widget, so I created a file `ProjectCoreBundle:Form:fields.html.twig` with the changes ... Now, how can I create a subdirectory in `Bundle/Resources/views/Form` folder, to use something like this: `ProjectCoreBundle:Form:Admin:fields.html.twig` (because I use CoreBundle for 'admin' and 'frontend', and I would like to separate these form customizations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load templates from subdirectories with this view syntax:

```
ProjectCoreBundle:Form:Admin/fields.html.twig
```

or

```
ProjectCoreBundle:Form/Admin:fields.html.twig
```

or

```
ProjectCoreBundle::Form/Admin/fields.html.twig
```

Comment: @elnur-abdurrakhimov is there anything wrong with this way: 'ProjectCoreBundle::Form/Admin/fields.html.twig' ... It works too for me.

Comment: @cbacelar, nothing wrong. It's a matter of taste, I guess. I prefer the 2nd form.

Comment: absolutely - personally i'd go for the second form aswell as it separates the bundle name, filename and the controller/path/purpose in the cleanest way.